# Implementing dup and dup2 using fcntl

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, call, fcntl

I'm implementing `dup` and `dup2` using `fcntl`, that what I have coded :

```
int dup(int oldfd) {
    return fcntl(oldfd, F_DUPFD, STDERR_FILENO);
}

int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd) {

    if(oldfd == newfd)
        return oldfd;

    if(fcntl(oldfd, F_GETFD) == -1)
        return -1;

    if(close(newfd) == -1 && errno != EBADF)
        return -1;

    fcntl(oldfd, F_DUPFD, newfd);

    return newfd;
}
```

But I see that the dup2 is not efficient at all(too much system call ==> too much kernel mode switch) and dup2 is not thread safe that me that a race condition can happen, because if between the ***close(newfd)*** and ***fcntl(oldfd, F_DUPFD, newfd)*** another thread take the control and open a file the file descriptor ***newfd*** will maybe be taken.

So how to make dup2 more efficient and thread-safe ?

Comment: "i must". Why? Is this some kind of homework? It is impossible to make this thread-safe.

Comment: yes its a homework, i think that its impossible to make it thread-safe is part of the answer

Comment: How about making it into a system call?  Seriously, there are reasons why system calls exist, and avoiding multiple system calls and race conditions are some of those reasons.